# Creating threads in Python iterations

Tags: python, multithreading, algorithm, selenium, loops

I want to make something like this:

A FOR in python that each iteration runs in a different Thread, and, mainly, print when the thread ends.

Basically I want to make some QA tests in wy website, and create a bunch os samples.

I have a great machine, so I want to use my CPU and Memory to optimizing this execution.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

for i in range(10):

    driver.get(myWebsite)
    print('Exec:  ' + str(i + 1))
    time.sleep(2)
```

How can I do this? I know how to use threads, but how to use to iterations or multiple actions?

Comment: this is not going to work, it's just like giving 4 mouses to 4 people to work on the same computer ... none of them will get any work done, you should be looking into multiprocessing not multithreading.

Comment: This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.